# How to quote values in php statement? Monday brain freeze

Tags: php, double-quotes

I have a piece of php code that reads values from a database resultset, shoves them into an array, and writes them to a CSV file. I need to force each value to be surrounded by double quotes when it goes into the CSV file, and can't for the life of me remember how to do this.

Here's the loop that writes to the file (this is actually contained in another loop to go through each row; this loop I'm showing goes through the columns in the currently-selected row):

```
foreach ($row as $key => $val){

    $newrow[$key] = preg_replace("(\r\n|\n|\r|\t)", "", $val);

}
```

fputcsv($fp, $newrow);

What I need is for the value of $val to be enclosed in double quotes when it's written to the file. Right now, the results I get look like this:

```
554,702180,25.00,6FYAK0,9090909090909090
```

What I need is this:

```
"554","702180","25.00","6FYAK0","9090909090909090"
```

Can someone jump start my brain?

Comment: having separate `\r\n` in the pattern seems a bit useless, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use substitute function for `fputscsv`:

```
function my_fputcsv($handle, $fieldsarray, $delimiter = ",", $enclosure ='"'){
    $glue = $enclosure . $delimiter . $enclosure;
    return fwrite($handle, $enclosure . implode($glue,$fieldsarray) . $enclosure);
}
```

Comment: I'll take a look at that first thing tomorrow morning; I'm shutting down for now.

Comment: Thanks, that worked exactly as I needed it to. I did have to add a \n to the end to make sure that the line breaks were created (for end-of-line), but otherwise just what I was looking for.

Comment: @EmmyS that's just overformalized version of Bailor's answer, who's got it plain and simple. Wonder why noone noticed that.

Answer (score 3):

HAve a look at the `fputscsv` command help on the PHP site: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

The fourth parameter specifies an enclosure character. Is this what you are looking for? From what I understand, though, a CSV put will only include the quotes if the field requires it because of either delimeter characters or enclosure characters included in the field itself.

Comment: Don't forget that PHP also supplies a `fgetscsv` command also which should be able to read from a file that PHP wrote.

Comment: I did try using the enclosure character, but as you said, it only puts the quotes around fields that are text-based in the database. We need to have ALL fields enclosed in quotes - the code is being passed to another system that requires it.

Comment: Then possibly best to write your own function: see my other answer :)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, if you read the requirement that the "other system requires" the quotes, then `fputscsv` isn't good enough since it will only put quotes around the fields that strictly require them. The other function is a simple way to guarantee that all fields have quotes. This doesn't.

Comment: I know, but it's still ugly. There are much better implementations around. Take a look.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick fix, but it works.

```
$value = '554,702180,25.00,6FYAK0,9090909090909090';

$new_value = '"' . implode('","', explode(',', $value)) . '"';

echo $new_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple enough:

```
 $newrow[$key] = '"' . preg_replace("(\r\n|\n|\r|\t)", "", $val) . '"';
```

Comment: You'd think so, but that's not what I get. What comes through using that code is this:  """554""","""702180""","""25.00""","""6FYAK0""","""9090909090909090"""

Answer (score -1):

IF you want to write it without using `fputscsv` then you could use a function similar to this to generate a line to write to a file:

```
function csvify ($array)
{
   $temp = "";
   $counter = 0;
   foreach ($array as $element)
   {
      if ($counter > 0)
         $temp = $temp . ",";
      $counter ++;
      $temp = $temp . "\"$element\"";
   }
   return $temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a little confused by this. You say if $counter > 0, but counter will always be zero in your code - it's not incrementing anywhere. And Which array am I passing in here - the array that's equivalent to a single row of the resultset, or the entire resultset?

Comment: Lol! Thanks @Col. Shrapnel... My concatenator was up the creek... Have edited and corrected.